# Space modified inside custom symbol

Tags: horizontal-spacing

How come my custom `\commonroot` symbol gets "destroyed" when being used 1 level deeper in the nesting?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}


\NewDocumentCommand{\lex}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m}{\lexAUX#1}

\NewDocumentCommand{\lexAUX}{mm}{%
    \textit{#1}%
    \IfValueT{#2}{\textup{\textsubscript{\textsc{#2}}}}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\commonroot}{}{%
    \raisebox{-0.5ex}{\rotatebox{45}{\textleftarrow\!\!}}\kern0.025em%
    \raisebox{0.5525ex}{\rotatebox{-45}{\!\!\textrightarrow}}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\coolsource}{mm}{%
    \textup{\{}\lex{#1}{\commonroot}\lex{#2}\textup{\}}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\coolderivback}{mm}{%
    \textup{\{}\lex{#1}\kern0.25em\textleftarrow\kern0.25em\lex{#2}\textup{\}}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\sourceback}{mmm}{%
    \coolderivback{\coolsource{#1}{#2}}{#3}}    


\begin{document}
    

        \coolsource{rétracter,v}{rétraction,n}
        
        \sourceback{rétracter,v}{rétraction,n}{retraire,v}
    

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

The actual symbol in my file, where I use *Times New Roman*, looks like on the following picture, and I don't want to use math mode:

[image]

Comment: What is the meaning of this symbol?

Comment: Both lexemes share a common ancestor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a printing character such as `!`

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\commonroot}{}{!%
    \raisebox{-0.5ex}{\rotatebox{45}{\textleftarrow\!\!}}\kern0.025em%
    \raisebox{0.553ex}{\rotatebox{-45}{\!\!\textrightarrow}}}
```

you see

[image]

which makes it clear you are in a different font setting.

adding `\textup` normalises things

[image]

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\commonroot}{}{\textup{!%
    \raisebox{-0.5ex}{\rotatebox{45}{\textleftarrow\!\!}}\kern0.025em%
    \raisebox{0.553ex}{\rotatebox{-45}{\!\!\textrightarrow}}}}
```

Comment: Wow, brilliant. I would never have thought of this, and yet it's so simple. Since `\lex` italicizes its content, we need to straighten whatever shouldn't be italicized. Thank you David!

Comment: Funny thing is, I did it with braces, and didn't think of doing it with the central symbol.

Answer (score 1):

You can use math symbols that are unaffected by the current text font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

% Define the 'lex' command for lexical entries
\NewDocumentCommand{\lex}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m}{\lexAUX#1}

% Auxiliary command to handle 'lex' arguments
\NewDocumentCommand{\lexAUX}{mm}{%
    \textit{#1}%
    \IfValueT{#2}{\textsubscript{\textup{\textsc{#2}}}}%
}

% Define the 'commonroot' symbol
%\NewDocumentCommand{\commonroot}{}{%
%    \raisebox{-0.5ex}{\rotatebox{45}{\textleftarrow\!\!}}\kern0.025em%
%    \raisebox{0.553ex}{\rotatebox{-45}{\!\!\textrightarrow}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\commonroot}{}{%
  \ensuremath{\scriptstyle{\swarrow}\mkern-2.6mu{\searrow}}%
}


% Define the 'coolsource' command
\NewDocumentCommand{\coolsource}{mm}{%
    \textup{\{}\lex{#1}{\commonroot}\lex{#2}\textup{\}}}

% Define the 'coolderivback' command
\NewDocumentCommand{\coolderivback}{mmg}{%
    \textup{\{}\lex{#1}\kern0.25em\textleftarrow\kern0.25em
    \lex{#2}\IfValueT{#3}{\kern0.25em\textleftarrow\kern0.25em
    \lex{#3}}\textup{\}}}

% Define the 'sourceback' command
\NewDocumentCommand{\sourceback}{mmm}{%
    \coolderivback{\coolsource{#1}{#2}}{#3}}    

\begin{document}
    
    \sourceback{rétracter,v}{rétraction,n}{retraire,v}
    
    \coolsource{rétracter,n}{rétraction,n}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can get arrows compatible with Times New Roman using STIX Two.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\newfontface{\arrows}{STIX Two Math}[Scale=0.7]

\NewDocumentCommand{\lex}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m}{\lexAUX#1}

\NewDocumentCommand{\lexAUX}{mm}{%
    \textit{#1}%
    \IfValueT{#2}{\textsubscript{\textup{\textsc{#2}}}}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\commonroot}{}{%
  \raisebox{\depth}{%
    \normalfont\arrows
    \kern0.225em
    \symbol{"2199}\kern-0.225em\symbol{"2198}%
    \kern0.225em
  }%
}
%\NewDocumentCommand{\commonroot}{}{%
%    \raisebox{-0.5ex}{\rotatebox{45}{\textleftarrow\!\!}}\kern0.025em%
%    \raisebox{0.5525ex}{\rotatebox{-45}{\!\!\textrightarrow}}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\coolsource}{mm}{%
    \textup{\{}\lex{#1}{\commonroot}\lex{#2}\textup{\}}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\coolderivback}{mm}{%
    \textup{\{}\lex{#1}\kern0.25em\textleftarrow\kern0.25em\lex{#2}\textup{\}}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\sourceback}{mmm}{%
    \coolderivback{\coolsource{#1}{#2}}{#3}}    


\begin{document}

        \coolsource{rétracter,v}{rétraction,n}
        
        \sourceback{rétracter,v}{rétraction,n}{retraire,v}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh yes but I want text mode. In my actual file the symbol looks like on the picture I have just added in my OP.

Comment: @VincentKrebs 1. Did I use math mode *in the document*? No. 2. The argument specifier `g` *requires* loading `xparse`.

Comment: Mh not sure why you make this distinction: with your definition of `\commonroot` I get a math-style font instead of the text font I want. Yeah on your advice I removed the *g* argument, so I removed `xparse` as well. Thanks!

Comment: @VincentKrebs Your example is too minimal. If you add what “Times New Roman” and what engine you use, I can surely adapt the answer to get arrows compatible with your setting.

Comment: `LuaTeX`. Loading `\fontspec` and the latest version of *Times New Roman*. And `amsmath[no-math]`, along with `amssymb`.

Comment: @VincentKrebs Added.

Comment: Many thanks. Did you notice how the subscripts fail to display in Small Caps?

Comment: I inverted `textup` and `textsubscript` hierarchical order and it works nicely, thanks !