# Custom Symbol - Simplified way

Tags: symbols, arrays

I have a custom symbol called `\trident`, which I programmed somehow awkwardly.

I'd like to use a more elegant method such as the one suggested to me by @egreg for my `\commonroot` symbol in this post:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/711580/262813

As illustrated in the MWE, the smart `\coolsource` command must be able to automatically choose which of the two symbols it should use, depending on which arguments are passed.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\newfontface{\arrows}{STIX Two Math}[Scale=0.7]


\NewDocumentCommand{\lex}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m}{\lexAUX#1}

\NewDocumentCommand{\lexAUX}{mm}{%
    \textit{#1}%
    \IfValueT{#2}{\textup{\textsubscript{\textsc{#2}}}}%
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\commonroot}{}{%
    \raisebox{\depth}{%
        \normalfont\arrows
        \kern0.225em
        \symbol{"2199}\kern-0.236em\symbol{"2198}%
        \kern0.225em
    }%
}



\newcommand{\trident}{%
    \raisebox{-0.6ex}{\rotatebox{45}{\textleftarrow\!\!}}%
    \kern0.025em%
    \makebox[0pt][c]{\kern0.05em\raisebox{-0.9ex}{\rotatebox{90}{\textleftarrow}}}%
\raisebox{0.453ex}{\rotatebox{-45}{\!\!\textrightarrow}}}
    
    

\NewDocumentCommand{\coolsource}{ommg}{%
    \IfValueTF{#1}{%
        $\hspace*{-1pt}\left\{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}}{%
            \IfValueTF{#4}{$\hspace*{-1pt}\left\{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}}{\textup{\{}}}%
            \lex{#2}%
            \kern0.25em%
            \IfValueTF{#4}{
                \trident%
                \raisebox{-2ex}{\kern-0.8em\makebox[0pt][c]{\lex{#4}}}% Adjust the -2ex as needed to position the text
            }{%
                % If the third argument is not provided, just use \commonroot
                \commonroot%
            }%
            \IfValueT{#1}{\IfValueF{#4}{\kern-0.8em}\raisebox{2.25ex}{\makebox[0pt][c]{\lex{#1}}}}%
            \IfValueTF{#4}{\kern1.05em}{\IfValueTF{#1}{\kern1.05em}{\kern0.25em}}%
            \lex{#3}%
            \IfValueTF{#1}{%
            \end{array} \right\}$}{%
            \IfValueTF{#4}{\end{array}\right\}$}{\textup{\}}}}}

\begin{document}
    
    \coolsource{contracter,v}{contraction,n}{contracture,n}
    
        \vspace*{2ex}
        
    \coolsource[contraire,v]{contracter,v}{contraction,n}{contracture,n}
    
        \vspace*{2ex}
        
    \coolsource[contraire,v]{contracter,v}{contraction,n}
    
        \vspace*{2ex}
        
    \coolsource{contracter,v}{contraction,n}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, I would have the use for a `\tetradent`, thus allowing to have two derivatives at the bottom instead of 1 (instead of the vertical southwards arrow, we would get two arrows, i.e. a SSW arrow and a SSE arrow; the #4/#5 optional argument would be split in two by a comma, and `\IfValueT{#5}` would trigger the *tetradent*). Again I could rotate a rightwards arrow with 67.5 and 112.5 angles, but maybe we could use `STIX Two` in this case too.

```
\newcommand{\tetradent}{%
    \raisebox{-0.5ex}{\rotatebox{45}{\textleftarrow\!\!}}%
    \kern0.025em%
    \makebox[0pt][c]{\kern-0.267em\raisebox{-0.845ex}{\rotatebox{67.5}{\textleftarrow}}}%
    \makebox[0pt][c]{\kern0.36em\raisebox{-0.41ex}{\rotatebox{112.5}{\textleftarrow}}}%
    \raisebox{0.553ex}{\rotatebox{-45}{\!\!\textrightarrow}}}
```

[image]

If I try to include the `\tetradent` case(s), and also a boolean to somehow distinguish the source lexeme by enclosing it inside a frame, I obtain a command that is unelegantly complex to handle in terms of the rightwards shifts in the possibility tree, and the compensating kerns to calculate and add.

*MWE*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\newfontface{\arrows}{STIX Two Math}[Scale=0.7]


\NewDocumentCommand{\lex}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m}{\lexAUX#1}

\NewDocumentCommand{\lexAUX}{mm}{%
    \textit{#1}%
    \IfValueT{#2}{\textup{\textsubscript{\textsc{#2}}}}%
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\commonroot}{}{%
    \raisebox{\depth}{%
        \normalfont\arrows
        \kern0.225em
        \symbol{"2199}\kern-0.236em\symbol{"2198}%
        \kern0.225em
    }%
}


\newcommand{\trident}{%
    \raisebox{-0.5ex}{\rotatebox{45}{\textleftarrow\!\!}}%
    \kern0.025em%
    \makebox[0pt][c]{\kern0.0518em\raisebox{-0.67ex}{\rotatebox{90}{\textleftarrow}}}%
    \raisebox{0.553ex}{\rotatebox{-45}{\!\!\textrightarrow}}}% Right arrow

\newcommand{\tetradent}{%
    \raisebox{-0.5ex}{\rotatebox{45}{\textleftarrow\!\!}}%
    \kern0.025em%
    \makebox[0pt][c]{\kern-0.267em\raisebox{-0.845ex}{\rotatebox{67.5}{\textleftarrow}}}%
    \makebox[0pt][c]{\kern0.36em\raisebox{-0.41ex}{\rotatebox{112.5}{\textleftarrow}}}%
    \raisebox{0.553ex}{\rotatebox{-45}{\!\!\textrightarrow}}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\coolsource}{sommgg}{%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
        $\hspace*{-1pt}\left\{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}}{%
            \IfValueTF{#5}{$\hspace*{-1pt}\left\{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}}{\textup{\{}}}%
            \IfValueTF{#6}{\lex{\footnotesize#3}}{\lex{#3}}%
            \kern0.25em%
            \IfValueTF{#5}{
                \IfValueTF{#6}{%
        \tetradent
    \raisebox{-2.5ex}{\kern-3em\makebox[0pt][c]{\lex{\footnotesize#5}}}%
    \raisebox{-2.5ex}{\kern4.5em\makebox[0pt][c]{\lex{\footnotesize#6}}}%
            }{%
                \trident%
            \raisebox{-2.5ex}{\kern-0.8em\makebox[0pt][c]{\lex{#5}}}%
            }}{%
                % If the third argument is not provided, just use \commonroot
                \commonroot%
            }%
            \IfValueT{#2}{\IfValueF{#5}{\kern-0.8em}{%
                    \IfValueT{#6}{\kern-2.2em}
                        \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\raisebox{3ex}{\makebox[0pt][c]{%
                            \tcbox[nobeforeafter, tcbox raise base,
                        colframe=black, boxrule=0.12ex, arc=0mm, 
                        boxsep=0pt, left=2pt, right=2pt, top=2pt, bottom=2pt]{\lex{#2}}}}}{%
                            \raisebox{2.5ex}{\makebox[0pt][c]{\lex{#2}}}}%
                        }}%
            \IfValueTF{#5}{\IfValueTF{#2}{\kern1.05em}{\IfValueTF{#6}{\kern-1.15em}{\kern1.05em}}}{\IfValueTF{#2}{\kern1.05em}{\kern0.25em}}%
                    \IfValueTF{#6}{\lex{\footnotesize#4}}{\lex{#4}}%%
            \IfValueTF{#2}{%
            \end{array}\right\}$}{%
            \IfValueTF{#5}{\end{array}\right\}$}{\textup{\}}}}}

\begin{document}
    
    \coolsource{contracter,v}{contraction,n}{contracture,n}
    
            \vspace*{2ex}
    
    \coolsource[contraire,v]{contracter,v}{contraction,n}{contracture,n}
        
            \vspace*{2ex}
    
    \coolsource[contraire,v]{contracter,v}{contraction,n}{contracture,n}{contracteur,n}
    
            \vspace*{2ex}
    
    \coolsource{contracter,v}{contraction,n}
    
            \vspace*{2ex}
    
    \coolsource{contracter,v}{contraction,n}{contracture,n}
    
            \vspace*{2ex}
    
    \coolsource{contracter,v}{contraction,n}{contracture,n}{contracteur,n}
    
            \vspace*{2ex}
    
    \coolsource*[contraire,v]{contracter,v}{contraction,n}{contracture,n}{contracteur,n}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To understand you correctly. You need an xparse command that can accept either 3 or four arguments, with the fourth being a g-type and then produce two different ouputs? Also your MWE needs a `\documentclass` etc...

Comment: Yes, just like I show. My command works fine as it is so I would just like a simplification in the spirit of what `egreg` suggested for `\commonroot`. Simplifying `\trident` is mostly what I want, but any idea to simplify `\coolsource` as well is welcome.

Comment: The g-type sometimes can be problematic. Consider a simpler interface, where you always pass the same number of arguments (easier to remember), but if the last one is empty, you choose a different symbol and text output. Or a `\cmd` and `\cmd*`.

Comment: I know the *g* argument is deprecated but I like it, it's more confusing for me to leave an argument empty or use square brackets. I guess we all have different ways of thinking. Anyway, the question is mostly about `\trident`. Also I didn't find the exact kern value to make the `\commonroot` symbol perfect using `egreg`'s def, the apex is still not perfect, I tried every possible refined value with even 4 digits but I can't obtain the perfect result as with my old definition, no idea why.

Comment: Agree you shouldn't use [] but in your code you have` {ommg}`. I had difficulties to understand exactly what you wanted, and thanks for the clarification.

Comment: The `o` argument is special as this is the source lexeme, it is optional but has a special status in the sense that it can be added with either two or three derivatives. The third derivative at the bottom is only needed when two derivatives are already present, which justifies using a rightwards *g* optional argument: that addresses cases 2 and 3 of *MWE*.

Comment: Another solution to avoid `g` is to use a comma-separated list.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Yes. This would be my preference as well and it can be fully automated, as `\cmd(wordN,..wordV)`, where the N and V can be replaced with subscripts. The star version can use the  `\commonroot` symbol and the unstarred the `\trident`. Any variadic function is best represented by a clist or sequence. One can go further and even get rid of the star, by inserting a "T," for trident as the first item in the list.

Comment: @yannisl But the whole point is that the command must be able to automatically select for the right symbol, as in my MWEs. Using a star is not what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly an answer, but I would probaby opt for an Expl-flavored Ti*k*Z solution which makes it much easier to draw the arrows and position the different parts. I would also make use of a comma-separated list (I changed the inner separator to a colon):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, fit}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% if the code does not compile try to uncomment the following line
% \cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set:Nn { Ne }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nee }
\seq_new:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_deriv_parts_seq
\cs_new:Npn \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format #1 {
    \seq_set_split:Nee \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_deriv_parts_seq { \c_colon_str } { #1 }
    \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_deriv_parts_seq { 1 } }
    \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpb_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_deriv_parts_seq { 2 } } 
    \textit{\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl} \tl_if_empty:NF \l_tmpb_tl {\textup{\textsubscript{\textsc{\tl_use:N \l_tmpb_tl}}}}
}

\clist_new:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_clist
\clist_new:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist
\NewDocumentCommand{\coolsource}{ o O{} m }{
    \clist_set:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_clist { #3 }
    \clist_clear:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a)]
        \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
        \IfValueT{#1}{
            \node[anchor=south, #2] (A) at (a) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { #1 } };
            \clist_push:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { (A) }
        }
        \coordinate (b) at (-1em,-0.6em);
        \coordinate (c) at (1em,-0.6em);
        \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_clist { 1 } }
        \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpb_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_clist { 2 } }
        \node[anchor=east] (B) at (b) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl } };
        \node[anchor=west] (C) at (c) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { \tl_use:N \l_tmpb_tl } };
        \draw[<->] (b.west) -- (a.south) -- (c.east);
        \clist_push:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { (B), (C) }

        \int_compare:nNnT { \clist_count:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_clist } > { 2 } {
            \int_compare:nNnTF { \clist_count:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_clist } > { 3 } {
                \coordinate (d) at (0em,-1.2em);
                \coordinate (e) at (0em,-1.2em);
                \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_clist { 3 } }
                \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpb_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_clist { 4 } }
                \node[anchor=north ~ east] (D) at (d) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl } };
                \node[anchor=north ~ west] (E) at (e) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { \tl_use:N \l_tmpb_tl } }; 
                \draw[->] (a.south) -- ([xshift=-0.5em]d.north);
                \draw[->] (a.south) -- ([xshift=0.5em]e.north);
                \clist_push:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { (D), (E) }
            } {
                \coordinate (d) at (0em,-1.2em);
                \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_clist { 3 } }
                \node[anchor=north] (D) at (d) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl } };  
                \draw[->] (a.south) -- (d.north);
                \clist_push:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { (D) }
            }
        } 
        
        \node[fit={ \clist_use:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { } }] (frame) {};
        \draw[decorate, decoration={brace, mirror}] (frame.north ~ west) -- (frame.south ~ west);
        \draw[decorate, decoration={brace}] (frame.north ~ east) -- (frame.south ~ east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\coolsource{contracter:v,contraction:n}

\coolsource{contracter:v,contraction:n,contracture:n}

\coolsource[contraire:v]{contracter:v,contraction:n,contracture:n}

\coolsource[contraire:v]{contracter:v,contraction:n,contracture:n,contracteur:n}

\coolsource[contraire:v][draw, fill=blue!10, yshift=2pt]{contracter:v,contraction:n,contracture:n,contracteur:n}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

With different delimiters (this variation would allow you to change the delimiters more easily as you can just change them in the code):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, fit}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% if the code does not compile try to uncomment the following line
% \cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set:Nn { Ne }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nee }
\seq_new:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_deriv_parts_seq
\cs_new:Npn \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format #1 {
    \seq_set_split:Nee \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_deriv_parts_seq { , } { #1 }
    \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_deriv_parts_seq { 1 } }
    \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpb_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_deriv_parts_seq { 2 } } 
    \textit{\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl} \tl_if_empty:NF \l_tmpb_tl {\textup{\textsubscript{\textsc{\tl_use:N \l_tmpb_tl}}}}
}

\seq_new:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq
\clist_new:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist
\NewDocumentCommand{\coolsource}{ o O{} m }{
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq { ; } { #3 }
    \clist_clear:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a), >=stealth]
        \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
        \IfValueT{#1}{
            \node[anchor=south, #2] (A) at (a) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { #1 } };
            \clist_push:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { (A) }
        }
        \coordinate (b) at (-1em,-0.6em);
        \coordinate (c) at (1em,-0.6em);
        \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq { 1 } }
        \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpb_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq { 2 } }
        \node[anchor=east] (B) at (b) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl } };
        \node[anchor=west] (C) at (c) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { \tl_use:N \l_tmpb_tl } };
        \draw[<->] (b.west) -- (a.south) -- (c.east);
        \clist_push:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { (B), (C) }

        \int_compare:nNnT { \seq_count:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq } > { 2 } {
            \int_compare:nNnTF { \seq_count:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq } > { 3 } {
                \coordinate (d) at (0em,-1.2em);
                \coordinate (e) at (0em,-1.2em);
                \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq { 3 } }
                \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpb_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq { 4 } }
                \node[anchor=north ~ east] (D) at (d) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl } };
                \node[anchor=north ~ west] (E) at (e) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { \tl_use:N \l_tmpb_tl } }; 
                \draw[->] (a.south) -- ([xshift=-0.5em]d.north);
                \draw[->] (a.south) -- ([xshift=0.5em]e.north);
                \clist_push:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { (D), (E) }
            } {
                \coordinate (d) at (0em,-1.2em);
                \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq { 3 } }
                \node[anchor=north] (D) at (d) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl } };  
                \draw[->] (a.south) -- (d.north);
                \clist_push:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { (D) }
            }
        } 
        
        \node[fit={ \clist_use:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { } }] (frame) {};
        \draw[decorate, decoration={brace, mirror}] (frame.north ~ west) -- (frame.south ~ west);
        \draw[decorate, decoration={brace}] (frame.north ~ east) -- (frame.south ~ east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\coolsource{contracter,v;contraction,n}

\coolsource{contracter,v;contraction,n;contracture,n}

\coolsource[contraire,v]{contracter,v;contraction,n;contracture,n}

\coolsource[contraire,v]{contracter,v;contraction,n;contracture,n;contracteur,n}

\coolsource[contraire,v][draw, fill=blue!10, yshift=2pt]{contracter,v;contraction,n;contracture,n;contracteur,n}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same as above (except for the different arrow heads that I changed to `stealth` according to your comment).

---

It seems that you alredy have some formatting command. You can totally just plug this into the `\coolsource` command if it makes things easier for you:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, fit}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% if the code does not compile try to uncomment the following line
% \cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set:Nn { Ne }
\clist_new:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_clist
\clist_new:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist
\NewDocumentCommand{\coolsource}{ o O{} m }{
    \clist_set:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_clist { #3 }
    \clist_clear:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a), >=stealth]
        \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
        \IfValueT{#1}{
            \node[anchor=south, #2] (A) at (a) { #1 };
            \clist_push:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { (A) }
        }
        \coordinate (b) at (-1em,-0.6em);
        \coordinate (c) at (1em,-0.6em);
        \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_clist { 1 } }
        \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpb_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_clist { 2 } }
        \node[anchor=east] (B) at (b) { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl };
        \node[anchor=west] (C) at (c) { \tl_use:N \l_tmpb_tl };
        \draw[<->] (b.west) -- (a.south) -- (c.east);
        \clist_push:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { (B), (C) }

        \int_compare:nNnT { \clist_count:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_clist } > { 2 } {
            \int_compare:nNnTF { \clist_count:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_clist } > { 3 } {
                \coordinate (d) at (0em,-1.2em);
                \coordinate (e) at (0em,-1.2em);
                \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_clist { 3 } }
                \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpb_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_clist { 4 } }
                \node[anchor=north ~ east] (D) at (d) { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl };
                \node[anchor=north ~ west] (E) at (e) { \tl_use:N \l_tmpb_tl }; 
                \draw[->] (a.south) -- ([xshift=-0.5em]d.north);
                \draw[->] (a.south) -- ([xshift=0.5em]e.north);
                \clist_push:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { (D), (E) }
            } {
                \coordinate (d) at (0em,-1.2em);
                \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_clist { 3 } }
                \node[anchor=north] (D) at (d) { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl };  
                \draw[->] (a.south) -- (d.north);
                \clist_push:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { (D) }
            }
        } 

        \node[fit={ \clist_use:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { } }] (frame) {};
        \draw[decorate, decoration={brace, mirror}] (frame.north ~ west) -- (frame.south ~ west);
        \draw[decorate, decoration={brace}] (frame.north ~ east) -- (frame.south ~ east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\lexAUX}{mm}{%
    \textit{#1}%
    \IfValueT{#2}{\textup{\textsubscript{\textsc{#2}}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\coolsource[\lexAUX{contraire}{v}]{\lexAUX{contracter}{v},\lexAUX{contraction}{n},\lexAUX{contracture}{n}}

\end{document}
```

But you can also modify the formatting commmand, so that it takes some syntax like `prefix:word,category,translation,addendum` (where `prefix`, `category`, `translation` and `addeddum` would be optional). I used a combination of Expl and traditional syntax here, because the newline character `\\`  has a special defintion in Ti*k*Z that seems to have to be treated with special care:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, fit}

\newcommand{\tslt}[1]{`#1'}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\IfEmptyF}{ m m }{
    \tl_if_empty:nF { #1 } { #2 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\formatnode}{ m m m m m }{%
    \IfEmptyF{#1}{#1 {}}%
    \IfEmptyF{#2}{\textit{#2}\nocorr}%
    \IfEmptyF{#3}{\textsubscript{\textup{\textsc{#3}}}}%
    \IfEmptyF{#4}{\\\tslt{#4}}%
    \IfEmptyF{#5}{ #5}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% if the code does not compile try to uncomment the following line
% \cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set:Nn { Ne }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nee }
\exp_args_generate:n { eeeee }
\cs_new:Npn \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format #1 {
    \seq_set_split:Nee \l_tmpa_seq { , } { #1 }
    \seq_set_split:Nee \l_tmpb_seq { \c_colon_str } { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 1 } }
    \int_compare:nNnTF { \seq_count:N \l_tmpb_seq } > { 1 } {
        \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { 1 } }
        \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpb_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { 2 } }
    } {
        \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {  }
        \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpb_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { 1 } }
    }
    \exp_args:Neeeee \formatnode{ \l_tmpa_tl }{ \l_tmpb_tl }{
        \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 2 } 
    }{
        \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 3 } 
    }{
        \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 4 } 
    }
}

\seq_new:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq
\clist_new:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist
\seq_new:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_deriv_parts_seq
\NewDocumentCommand{\coolsource}{ o O{} m }{
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq { ; } { #3 }
    \clist_clear:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a), >=stealth, every ~ node/.append ~ style={align=center}]
        \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
        \IfValueT{#1}{
            \node[anchor=south, #2] (A) at (a) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { #1 } };
            \clist_push:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { (A) }
        }
        \coordinate (b) at (-1em,-0.6em);
        \coordinate (c) at (1em,-0.6em);
        \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq { 1 } }
        \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpb_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq { 2 } }
        \node[anchor=north ~ east, yshift=0.8em] (B) at (b) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl } };
        \node[anchor=north ~ west, yshift=0.8em] (C) at (c) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { \tl_use:N \l_tmpb_tl } };
        \draw[<->] (b.west) -- (a.south) -- (c.east);
        \clist_push:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { (B), (C) }

        \int_compare:nNnT { \seq_count:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq } > { 2 } {
            \int_compare:nNnTF { \seq_count:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq } > { 3 } {
                \coordinate (d) at (0em,-1.2em);
                \coordinate (e) at (0em,-1.2em);
                \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq { 3 } }
                \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpb_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq { 4 } }
                \node[anchor=north ~ east] (D) at (d) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl } };
                \node[anchor=north ~ west] (E) at (e) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { \tl_use:N \l_tmpb_tl } }; 
                \draw[->] (a.south) -- ([xshift=-0.5em]d.north);
                \draw[->] (a.south) -- ([xshift=0.5em]e.north);
                \clist_push:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { (D), (E) }
            } {
                \coordinate (d) at (0em,-1.2em);
                \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq { 3 } }
                \node[anchor=north] (D) at (d) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl } };  
                \draw[->] (a.south) -- (d.north);
                \clist_push:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { (D) }
            }
        } 
        
        \node[fit={ \clist_use:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { } }] (frame) {};
        \draw[decorate, decoration={brace, mirror}] (frame.north ~ west) -- (frame.south ~ west);
        \draw[decorate, decoration={brace}] (frame.north ~ east) -- (frame.south ~ east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\coolsource[pre:contraire,v,foo,bar]{pre:contracter,v;contraction,n,foo;contracture,n,foo,bar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Maybe you need to align things differently if you want to put more text in the second line of the nodes.

Comment: Wow thanks for your time, this is indeed an elegant solution, although involving a drastically different approach. Well done! However, your code doesn't compile (\coolsource yields an undefined cs). I use LuaTeX, can it be related ? Most probably a package not loaded.

Comment: @VincentKrebs WIth a recent installation of TeX Live, it should work. What is the error exactly? You only need to load `tikz` for it to work.

Comment: @VincentKrebs The code compiles on https://texlive.net/run .

Comment: @VincentKrebs This looks very strange. It seems that spaces are ignored somewhere, but I did use `~` in the code to prevent this. Tell me the first error the log shows

Comment: Undefined control sequence. \coolsource{contracter:v,contraction:n}

Comment: Ok after updating, now it compiles fine.

Comment: @VincentKrebs Most likely, the error could have been solved by putting `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set:Nn { Ne }` in the code.

Comment: Ok if you say so :) As you can see those are normal caps, not small caps. And yet i see you have used \textsc. I admit I'm a bit lost in this code, not so familiar with expl3

Comment: @VincentKrebs Sorry, you are right. You need to replace `\tl_set:Ne \l_tmpb_tl { \exp_args:Ne \str_uppercase:n { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_deriv_parts_seq { 2 } } }` with `\tl_set:Ne \l_tmpb_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_deriv_parts_seq { 2 } }`. I updated the code above.

Comment: @VincentKrebs Not exactly the same style, but you can add `>=stealth` to the option list of the `tikzpicture` (that is, change `[baseline=(a)]` to `[baseline=(a), >=stealth]`).

Comment: I promise I've tried, but I cannot succeed to changing the delimiters. I want to keep the comma between lexeme and category; but semicolons between arguments of the split.

Comment: @VincentKrebs This does not work easily, because I chose to use a `clist`. But you can change to a `seq`. I'll change the code and add it to my answer in a moment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151726/discussion-between-vincent-krebs-and-jasper-habicht).

Comment: If I draw a circle instead, can I reduce the radius? (without editing the code any more, just in acse there is a simple syntax)

Answer (score 1):

`Jasper`'s code works very nicely and allows for all desirable tweaks: here is an example, with a style close to that used in the OP.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, fit}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% if the code does not compile try to uncomment the following line
% \cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set:Nn { Ne }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nee }
\seq_new:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_deriv_parts_seq
\cs_new:Npn \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format #1 {
    \seq_set_split:Nee \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_deriv_parts_seq { , } { #1 }
    \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_deriv_parts_seq { 1 } }
    \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpb_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_deriv_parts_seq { 2 } } 
    \textit{\l_tmpa_tl} \tl_if_empty:NF \l_tmpb_tl {\textup{\textsubscript{\textsc{\l_tmpb_tl}}}}
}

\seq_new:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq
\clist_new:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist
\NewDocumentCommand{\coolsource}{ o O{} m }{
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq { ; } { #3 }
    \clist_clear:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a), >=stealth,line~width=0.5pt]
        \coordinate (a) at (0,0.25em);
        \IfValueT{#1}{
            \node[anchor=south, #2] (A) at (a) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { #1 } };
            \clist_push:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { (A) }
        }
        \coordinate (b) at (-1em,-0.6em);
        \coordinate (c) at (1em,-0.6em);
        \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq { 1 } }
        \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpb_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq { 2 } }
        \node[anchor=east] (B) at (b) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { \l_tmpa_tl } };
        \node[anchor=west] (C) at (c) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { \l_tmpb_tl } };
        \draw[<->] (b.west) -- (a.south) -- (c.east);
        \clist_push:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { (B), (C) }
        
        \int_compare:nNnT { \seq_count:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq } > { 2 } {
            \int_compare:nNnTF { \seq_count:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq } > { 3 } {
                \coordinate (d) at (0em,-0.9em);
                \coordinate (e) at (0em,-0.9em);
                \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq { 3 } }
                \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpb_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq { 4 } }
                \node[anchor=north ~ east] (D) at (d) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { \l_tmpa_tl } };
                \node[anchor=north ~ west] (E) at (e) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { \l_tmpb_tl } }; 
                \draw[->] (a.south) -- ([xshift=-0.5em]d.north);
                \draw[->] (a.south) -- ([xshift=0.5em]e.north);
                \clist_push:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { (D), (E) }
            } {
                \coordinate (d) at (0em,-0.9em);
                \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq { 3 } }
                \node[anchor=north] (D) at (d) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { \l_tmpa_tl } };  
                \draw[->] (a.south) -- (d.north);
                \clist_push:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { (D) }
            }
        } 

        \node[fit={ \clist_use:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { } }] (frame) {};
        \draw[decorate, semithick, decoration={brace, amplitude=2pt, mirror}] ([xshift=0.5em,yshift=-0.3em]frame.north ~ west) -- ([xshift=0.5em,yshift=0.3em]frame.south ~ west);
        \draw[decorate, semithick, decoration={brace, amplitude=2pt}] ([xshift=-0.5em,yshift=-0.3em]frame.north ~ east) -- ([xshift=-0.5em,yshift=0.3em]frame.south ~ east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\coolsource{contracter,v;contraction,n}

\coolsource{contracter,v;contraction,n;contracture,n}

\coolsource[contraire,v]{contracter,v;contraction,n;contracture,n}

\coolsource[contraire,v]{contracter,v;contraction,n;contracture,n;contracteur,n}

\coolsource[contraire,v][draw, fill=blue!10, yshift=0.4em]{contracter,v;contraction,n;contracture,n;contracteur,n}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]