# Vertical alignment of node text in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

Can someone tell me why the text is top-aligned, i.e. for instance the dot on the *i* letter shifts the text downwards, but the *o* remains sticked to the top, such causing misalignment between the two nodes?

I want the text centered vertically, both letters, *i* and *o* being at the same height.

The code is by @JasperHabicht:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/711612/262813

I tried to adjust the settings and came up with:

> [baseline=(a), >=stealth,every node/.style={minimum height=10ex,text depth=10ex,align=center}]`

but without success.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, fit}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nee }
\seq_new:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_deriv_parts_seq
\cs_new:Npn \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format #1 {
    \seq_set_split:Nee \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_deriv_parts_seq { , } { #1 }
    \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_deriv_parts_seq { 1 } }
    \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpb_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_deriv_parts_seq { 2 } } 
    \textit{\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl} \tl_if_empty:NF \l_tmpb_tl {\textup{\textsubscript{\textsc{\tl_use:N \l_tmpb_tl}}}}
}

\seq_new:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq
\clist_new:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist


\NewDocumentCommand{\coolsource}{ o O{} m }{
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq { ; } { #3 }
    \clist_clear:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a), >=stealth,every node/.style={minimum height=10ex,text depth=10ex,align=center}]
        \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
        \IfValueT{#1}{
            \node[anchor=south, #2] (A) at (a) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { #1 } };
            \clist_push:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { (A) }
        }
        \coordinate (b) at (-1em,-0.6em);
        \coordinate (c) at (1em,-0.6em);
        \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq { 1 } }
        \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpb_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq { 2 } }
        \node[anchor=east] (B) at (b) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl } };
        \node[anchor=west] (C) at (c) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { \tl_use:N \l_tmpb_tl } };
        \draw[<->] (b.west) -- (a.south) -- (c.east);
        \clist_push:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { (B), (C) }
        
        \int_compare:nNnT { \seq_count:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq } > { 2 } {
            \int_compare:nNnTF { \seq_count:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq } > { 3 } {
                \coordinate (d) at (0em,-1.2em);
                \coordinate (e) at (0em,-1.2em);
                \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq { 3 } }
                \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpb_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq { 4 } }
                \node[anchor=north ~ east] (D) at (d) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl } };
                \node[anchor=north ~ west] (E) at (e) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { \tl_use:N \l_tmpb_tl } }; 
                \draw[->] (a.south) -- ([xshift=-0.5em]d.north);
                \draw[->] (a.south) -- ([xshift=0.5em]e.north);
                \clist_push:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { (D), (E) }
            } {
                \coordinate (d) at (0em,-1.2em);
                \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq { 3 } }
                \node[anchor=north] (D) at (d) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl } };  
                \draw[->] (a.south) -- (d.north);
                \clist_push:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { (D) }
            }
        } 
        
        \node[fit={ \clist_use:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { } }] (frame) {};
        \draw[decorate, decoration={brace, mirror}] (frame.north ~ west) -- (frame.south ~ west);
        \draw[decorate, decoration={brace}] (frame.north ~ east) -- (frame.south ~ east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \coolsource{ion,n;ory,n;i,n;i,n}
    
    
    \coolsource{ion,n;ory,n;o,n;o,n}
    
    
    \coolsource{ion,n;ory,n;i,n;o,n}
    
    
    \coolsource{ion,n;ory,n;o,n;i,n}
    
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

After @cfr's correction, the optional shape around (A) is anchored to low:

```
\begin{document}
    
    
    \coolsource[source,v][draw]{ion,n;ory,n;i,n;i,n}
    
    
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

The solution is just to keep `anchor=south` in **node (A)'s settings**.

Comment: Try `anchor=base` rather than `anchor=south`. (Untested.)

Comment: Please don't use custom fonts in examples unless essential. This may compile for you, but it won't compile for me.

Comment: Exactly. You want the text in one node to align with the text in another, you do it by aligning their anchors. If you don't want to change the position of some the nodes then what do you want? If you align nodes using their `north` anchors, for example, the dot of your `i` will be aligned with the top of your `o`. Either you change the anchors you're aligning or, if you really don't want that, you could add `\strut` to all of them. But that would still look as if you were moving them.

Comment: Sorry I initially misunderstood your advice, I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

I can't compile your example as is, so I removed the custom font setup. To align nodes on the baseline, use `base`, `base west`, `base east` etc. I'm guessing that's what you want but, if you really do want it centred, use `center`, `west` and `east` instead.

[image: nodes aligned to base]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, fit}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nee }
\seq_new:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_deriv_parts_seq
\cs_new:Npn \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format #1 {
    \seq_set_split:Nee \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_deriv_parts_seq { , } { #1 }
    \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_deriv_parts_seq { 1 } }
    \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpb_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_deriv_parts_seq { 2 } } 
    \textit{\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl} \tl_if_empty:NF \l_tmpb_tl {\textup{\textsubscript{\textsc{\tl_use:N \l_tmpb_tl}}}}
}

\seq_new:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq
\clist_new:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist


\NewDocumentCommand{\coolsource}{ o O{} m }{
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq { ; } { #3 }
  \clist_clear:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a), >=stealth]
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    \IfValueT{#1}{
      \node[anchor=south, #2] (A) at (a) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { #1 } };
      \clist_push:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { (A) }
    }
    \coordinate (b) at (-1em,-0.6em);
    \coordinate (c) at (1em,-0.6em);
    \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq { 1 } }
    \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpb_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq { 2 } }
    \node[anchor=base ~ east] (B) at (b) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl } };
    \node[anchor=base ~ west] (C) at (c) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { \tl_use:N \l_tmpb_tl } };
    \draw[<->] (b.west) -- (a.south) -- (c.east);
    \clist_push:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { (B), (C) }
    
    \int_compare:nNnT { \seq_count:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq } > { 2 } {
      \int_compare:nNnTF { \seq_count:N \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq } > { 3 } {
        \coordinate (d) at (0em,-1.2em);
        \coordinate (e) at (0em,-1.2em);
        \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq { 3 } }
        \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpb_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq { 4 } }
        \node[anchor=north ~ east] (D) at (d) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl } };
        \node[anchor=base ~ west] (E) at (e |- D.base) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { \tl_use:N \l_tmpb_tl } }; 
        \draw[->] (a.south) -- ([xshift=-0.5em]d.north);
        \draw[->] (a.south) -- ([xshift=0.5em]e.north);
        \clist_push:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { (D), (E) }
      } {
        \coordinate (d) at (0em,-1.2em);
        \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_derivs_seq { 3 } }
        \node[anchor=north] (D) at (d) { \vincentkrebs_coolsource_format { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl } };  
        \draw[->] (a.south) -- (d.north);
        \clist_push:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { (D) }
      }
    } 
    
    \node[fit={ \clist_use:Nn \l_vincentkrebs_coolsource_fitspec_clist { } }] (frame) {};
    \draw[decorate, decoration={brace, mirror}] (frame.north ~ west) -- (frame.south ~ west);
    \draw[decorate, decoration={brace}] (frame.north ~ east) -- (frame.south ~ east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \coolsource{ion,n;ory,n;i,n;i,n}
    
    
    \coolsource{ion,n;ory,n;o,n;o,n}
    
    
    \coolsource{ion,n;ory,n;i,n;o,n}
    
    
    \coolsource{ion,n;ory,n;o,n;i,n}
    
    
\end{document}
```

It's not clear to me that the use of `expl3` does a lot for you here. Just be aware that this syntax is not necessarily compatible with pgf/tikz syntax, so it is entirely possible you may run into conflicts. That said, I mix them also - just you need to be a bit wary of the potential pitfalls.

Comment: Yes we ran into problems with line breaks, you're right.

Comment: @VincentKrebs Note that your `every node` isn't being applied either because what you've done is define a new style `everynode` which you never use. You need `every ~ node` in this context. Similarly, `minimum ~ height`, `text ~ depth` and so on.

Comment: The font does not matter at all, results are the same here. But I got what you meant, I usually do not include the font but here I did.

Comment: Not sure what it is meant to look like, but I suspect you don't want some of that `every node` style? @VincentKrebs

Comment: I just removed every node and all, that was just some trial to fix it. I see you have replaced (e) with (e |- D.base), it works only with this. Thanks!

Comment: @VincentKrebs Yes, because I wanted it aligned with `D`'s `base` only vertically and not horizontally. Otherwise you are just putting the second node on top of the first!

Comment: And yet we didn't have to do that for B and C, what's the catch? I mean we just wrote (C) at (c). Can't figure it out.

Comment: @VincentKrebs Because `(b)` and `(c)` are different coordinates but `(d)` and `(e)` are identical. So if you align the two nodes at `(d)` and `(e)` and use the same anchor, they will be one on top of the other.

Comment: But I tried giving -0.1em for the x of (d) and +0.1em for the x of (e), and even here, it doesn't work without your e |- D.base.

Comment: @VincentKrebs That's because you're aligning B and C on `y=0.6em`, so it is enough to make sure the `base` anchor is used. But you don't know what `y` should be for D and E. Rather, you're aligning the first one by hanging it from `north`. Then you want to align the second to whatever-y-corresponds-to-y-at-`base`-of-D.